# Changing tab size/length in a User Defined Language in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to change the tab length in a UDL in notepad++?
It's easy enough to change for a defined language in the langs.xml file. However, can't seem to figure it out for a UDL.

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [How do you setup tab settings for user defined file types in notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6051919/2738262)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `userdefinelang.xml` where UDL's are stored, it is not there. So the answer is: if it is not stored, it is not taken into account. So it is currently not possible.

Of course, you can clone your Notepad++ directory and edit your UDL files using that clone of Notepad++ which will have set different tab size.